# Unable to access the nginx through Kubernetes LoadBalancer service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I'm using k8s provided with docker desktop (windows).

My deployment.yml file is

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and my service yml file is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31000
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

all are up and running but I'm unable to access the application.

```
>curl localhost:31000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 31000: Connection refused

>kubectl get all
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-deployment-685658ccbf-g84w5   1/1     Running   0          8s

NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP        14h
service/my-service   LoadBalancer   10.96.210.40   localhost     80:31000/TCP   4s

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment   1/1     1            1           8s

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-deployment-685658ccbf   1         1         1       8s
```

Note: created the Inbound/Outbound rule for this 31000 port in windows firewall to make sure it won't block

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions you can try to answer in order to [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/):

1. [Does the Service exist?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-exist): In your case we see that it does.
2. [Does the Service work by DNS name?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-work-by-dns-name): One of the most common ways that clients consume a Service is through a DNS name.
3. [Does the Service work by IP?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-work-by-ip): Assuming you have confirmed that DNS works, the next thing to test is whether your Service works by its IP address.
4. [Is the Service defined correctly?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-the-service-defined-correctly): You should really double and triple check that your Service is correct and matches your Pod's port. Also:

- Is the Service port you are trying to access listed in `spec.ports[]`?
- Is the `targetPort` correct for your Pods (some Pods use a different port than the Service)?
- If you meant to use a numeric port, is it a number (9376) or a string "9376"?
- If you meant to use a named port, do your Pods expose a port with the same name?
- Is the port's `protocol` correct for your Pods?

5. [Does the Service have any Endpoints?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints): Check that the Pods you ran are actually being selected by the Service.
6. [Are the Pods working?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#are-the-pods-working): Check again that the Pods are actually working.
7. [Is the kube-proxy working?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#is-the-kube-proxy-working): Confirm that `kube-proxy` is running on your Nodes.

Going through the above steps will help you find the cause of this and possible future issues with services.